# Excel: Create a fitted lognormal curve to histogram data

Tags: excel

I am struggling a bit on making a lognormal curve fitting for a dataset:

[image: Histogram]

The cumulative share of "occurences" goes from:

0.25 to 0.75%, between

X=0.2 to 0.4, as will be seen in the next figure: [image: Share of occurences and excel-functions]

I am trying to make a "analytical" lognormal curve for the dataset. But when I use the excel-function  LOGNORM.DIST() (both cumulative and density functions, they miss a lot, and I really don't understand why.
I would like to share the spreadsheet for anyone who wants to take a look, but it seems it isn't possible here in stackoverflow?